# Zotac ZBOX CI323-Nano-U goes blank when second display is attached (Fedora 27 Cinnamon X)

Tags: fedora, xorg, i915

The Zotac CI323 has DisplayPort, HDMI, and VGA outputs.
It is running Fedora 27 Cinnamon with X.
`lspci -v` shows an `x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx` with kernel module `i915` in use

Any single digital display connection works on either the DisplayPort or the HDMI port.  Either may be shown as a single HDMI of the same number (i.e. `xrandr` shows `HDMI3` for me when the display cable is in one port or the other).

Connecting two displays simultaneously causes both of the displays to go into power save.
When either display cable is removed, the remaining display goes active again.

It should automatically reconfigure for both displays.

*(I solved this and am going to post my answer below)*

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. create an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, containing:

`Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "Intel"
    Option "ReprobeOutputs" "true"
EndSection`

2. ...then restart X.
   That's it.
3. You may need to open the display settings to fix the geometry.  Also, it may detect 3 displays (when 2 are connected), one of which is a duplicative entry that can be disabled.

(sidebar:  I did not need to add module options to `i915`.  I was considering playing with `lvds_channel_mode`, use `modinfo -p i915` to see.)